# my tableadapter are generating datetime2 fields as string

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, tableadapter

Im using tableAdapters to insert values to a table.

Heres my table `aaTest`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[aaTest](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[INVOICEDATE] [datetime2](0) NULL,
[CHARGEDATE] [datetime2](0) NULL,
[EZPASS] [varchar](50) NULL,
[PLAZA] [varchar](10) NULL,
[PLAZA2] [varchar](10) NULL,
[PDATE] [datetime2](0) NULL,
[PTIME] [varchar](9) NULL,
[PAMOUNT] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
[PBALANCE] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
[ACTION] [varchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

in my dataset, my initial fill command is `select * from aatest`, and ive created an insert query

```
INSERT INTO [aatest] ([INVOICEDATE], [CHARGEDATE], [EZPASS], [PLAZA], [PLAZA2], [PDATE], [PTIME], [PAMOUNT], [PBALANCE], [ACTION])
VALUES (@INVOICEDATE, @CHARGEDATE, @EZPASS, @PLAZA, @PLAZA2, @PDATE, @PTIME, @PAMOUNT, @PBALANCE, @ACTION)
```

now under my dataset designer, my query is being declared as such

```
public virtual int InsertQuery(string INVOICEDATE, string CHARGEDATE, string EZPASS, string PLAZA, string PLAZA2, string PDATE, string PTIME, global::System.Nullable<decimal> PAMOUNT, global::System.Nullable<decimal> PBALANCE, string ACTION)
```

the problem im having is, `INVOICEDATE`, `CHARGEDATE` and `PDATE` are being generated as strings when they are in fact `datetime2`. this causes the exception

> The best overloaded method match for (mydataset) has some invalid arguments.

changing it to datetime worked temporary, but after a while they regenerated back to strings.

Comment: try a regular datetime instead of a datetime2. I think tableadapters are older technology that might not recognize the new sql server datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `[datetime2]` to just `[datetime]`, that should fix your issue.

Comment: yea i did a bit reasearch and as jeremy mentioned, tableadapters  are old and doesnt reconize `datetime2` or `date`